# AbstractFactory design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have created a following example . does this follows AbstractFactory design pattern ?

**ButtonType.java**

```
public enum ButtonType {
    WIN, LINUX, MAC
}
```

**Button.java**

```
public interface Button {
    ButtonType getButtonType();

    void actionListener();
}
```

**LinuxButton.java**

```
public class LinuxButton implements Button {

    @Override
    public ButtonType getButtonType() {
        return ButtonType.LINUX;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionListener() {
        System.out.println("Linux Button created");

    }

}
```

**WinButton.java**

```
public class WinButton implements Button {

    @Override
    public ButtonType getButtonType() {
        return ButtonType.WIN;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionListener() {
        System.out.println("Window Button Created");

    }

}
```

**MacButton.java**

```
public class MacButton implements Button {

    @Override
    public ButtonType getButtonType() {
        return ButtonType.MAC;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionListener() {
        System.out.println("Mac Button Created");

    }

}
```

**ButtonFactory.java**

```
public interface ButtonFactory {

    Button createButton();
}
```

**LinuxButtonFactory.java**

```
public class LinuxButtonFactory implements ButtonFactory {

    @Override
    public Button createButton() {
        System.out.println("creating Linux Button");
        return new LinuxButton();
    }

}
```

**WinButtonFactory.java**

```
public class WinButtonFactory implements ButtonFactory {

    @Override
    public Button createButton() {
        System.out.println("creating window Button");
        return new WinButton();
    }

}
```

**MacButtonFactory.java**

```
public class MacButtonFactory implements ButtonFactory {

    @Override
    public Button createButton() {
        System.out.println("Creating MAC Button");
        return new MacButton();
    }

}
```

**AbstractButtonFactory.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractButtonFactory {

    public static ButtonFactory getButtonFactory(ButtonType bt) {
        ButtonFactory btnFactory = null;
        switch (bt) {
        case WIN:
            btnFactory = new WinButtonFactory();
            break;
        case LINUX:
            btnFactory = new LinuxButtonFactory();
            break;
        default:
            btnFactory = new MacButtonFactory();
        }
        return btnFactory;
    }

}
```

and finally the main calss

```
public class AbstractFactoryObjectDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ButtonFactory factory = AbstractButtonFactory.getButtonFactory(ButtonType.LINUX);
        Button linuxButton = factory.createButton();
        System.out.println(linuxButton.getButtonType().toString());
    }

}
```

I want to make sure is this pattern follow AbstractFactory Design Pattern ,if it doesn't what changes should be made?

Comment: You've abstracted the button and the factory - looks good to me. Where are your special concerns?

Comment: @Andreas_D : AbstractButtonFactory.java , is it correct impl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is ok. You have abstracted the button and the factory and that's the main goal for the pattern.

On an implementation side note: the `getButtonFactory` method on the factory is pretty useless, you can simply remove it an all the implementations from the real factories.

When a user calls the static method on the abstract factory, he already gets an instance of a factory and doesn't have to call a method on this factory which simply would return itself again. So drop this method :)

Comment: Looks good to me and I'd implement it the same way. To me it fulfills the requirements that are set by the pattern itself.

Comment: @Andreas_D Using the *Abstract Factory* pattern in this case is an overkill IMO.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but I think, that was more an academic question/task.

Comment: The Abstract Factory is for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes not for creating a single object. Also, why would the OP keep the interface separated from the abstract factory ? The contract is related to the abstract factory class and should be in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the interface

```
public interface ButtonFactory {
    ButtonFactory getButtonFactory(ButtonType bt);
    Button createButton();
}
```

Into 2 different ones

```
public interface ButtonFactory {
    ButtonCreator getButtonFactory(ButtonType bt);
}
```

and

```
public Button ButtonCreator {
    Button createButton();
}
```

First one creates ButtonCreator (depending on type) and ButtonCreator keeps the type inside and creates button of the type

:Updated

Comment: I didn't get you last coding snippet

Comment: Updated the snippet

Comment: ButtonFactory is a useless interface for a useless method,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider combination between [Bridge](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Bridge/) and [Abstract Factory](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/AbstractFactory/).

Imagine that you have a need to add new graphical item in addition to Button let say ComboBox, or that you have additional platform in addition to Win/Linux/Mac.
Then pure Abstract Factory will not be flexible, therefore Bridge pattern can be used in order to separate abstraction(Button, ComboBox, ...) and platform specific implementation(Win/Linux/Mac).